# Multiple voltage measurement

Tags: voltage-measurement

I have to measure voltage for about 100 different channels in one object and the problems is space for equipment (100 transducers would require lots of space) and price of transducers. 
Is there a way to use some kind of relay switch/commutator to change the channels for one sensor? For example it would be great to make 10 measurements by one sensor when using additional device to change the channels (by time or by input from other device..).
All the voltages are almost the same ~220-240V AC and some ~12-24V DC. 
All ideas are welcome and very much appreciated.
Here is basic scheme of the measuring devices integration:
[image]

Comment: what sensor are you using?

Comment: Show a schematic of how you plan to measure one channel then it might be possible to modify this to use a multiplexer.

Comment: Are you actually measuring VOLTAGE, or just trying to determine if something is on or off? Multiplexing to actually measure an AC voltage is going to be either costly, or slow due to settling time.

Comment: Now i have TEMA TM2UA94, output 4-20mV, to moxa PLC. I need to measure actual voltage... I don't have the scheme yet, just trying to imagine how it should work. This system should measure voltage of point switching machine (used in railways) 3 phases (220V AC). And in one station there is about 10 Point machines, so ~30 phases to measure... I'll try to prepare a scheme of the measurements.

Comment: Work out one channel then come back here and ask questions.

Comment: Keysight, & Tektronix/Keithley (at least) make an instrument called a scanning multimeter, which is basically an array of relays in front of a multimeter. I'm not sure if they have one to meet your requirements (240 V AC measurements), but the channel count would be no problem.

Comment: Sensor work on 36kV ? What is your sensor or input type ? Analog(Xmin,Xmax),Digital(Fixed X volts),PWM(Xhz-min-Xhz-max), please add some information about of input point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that we come to the point where the real design (with component cost optimization etc) starts.

I suggest using AC resonant (50 or 60 Hz) pre-filter with low Quality Factor (5-10). The rectifier must be made of 2 low leakage low current low frequency rectifier diodes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNEDlJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Values and P/N of all components except R3 R4 are arbitrary.

R3 R4 give you an idea about the required total resistance and voltage divider ratio. I suggest not to use filter capacitor on the output or use moderate filtering: the ADC measurements must be synchronized to Mains.

The DC power +5 V for low signal electronics has to be delivered from Mains.

You can use a common MCU to control ADC and analog switch and to send data by some standard digital line. The latest has to isolated from MCU by a proper digital isolator (consider using AD SOIC-8 digital isolators or TI similar one: ISO7221C or M, ISO7220C/M). Built-in ADC (into MCU) is a good and cost effective option. The true 12 bits ADC is enough to get about 0.1 V (related to input) resolution and about 0.2 V (again related to input) typical error.

The care must be taken about:

1. Leakage currents of D1 D2 over the whole intended temperature range (they must be much smaller than nominal current of R3 R4 divider: less than 1 uA, this may be difficult)
2. Voltage rating and AC performance of C1
3. Cost effective and compact design of L1
4. Precision and temperature coefficient of R3 R4
5. R2 can be either equal to R3+R4 for symmetric load or small - for double voltage rectifier (not recommended)

As for the switch - look for a suitable one for example on AD site. You need 5 V unipolar switch - they are good and relatively cheap.

The number of channels per one ADC input depends on conversion time (sampling frequency) of the ADC. I use typically 1 MS/s ADCs. Then you can sample 16 channels in 20-30 us.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider several problems before drafting the circuits:

1. How far from each other are the measurement points?
2. What are the precision requirements? Say, +-1% is far different from +-5%.
3. What is the format of measurement result: digital data or human readable?
4. Cost requirements

Comment: 1. Measurements points are in same cable cross cabinet (Inside-Outside cables). And there is free space to connect measuring equipment(Double WAGO clamps are used).
2. -+5% is enough to see when the device is starting to work not as it should be working.
3. Measurement results will be collected in data analysis manager, to compare, set tresholds and etc... Digital data.
4. Let's say price is quite important, because there will be a lot of measurements. For the start it would be good to make 10 measurements with something like ~500Eu (only for measuring equipment).

Answer (score 0):

I did not get from your answers - what precision do you actually need?

And there is another question: do you measure the voltage between PHASES HI1, ... and common ZERO line or you need to measure voltages with isolation on both lines?

Basically, the reasonable design uses low cost rectifiers on each AC line. The switching device operates on low voltage DC (from 0 to 10 V or - better - from 0 to 5 V). This design may give costs less than USD 100 per 16 channels.

The weak point of this design is: sensitivity to spikes and distortions on AC lines. This can fixed by proper filtering.

Comment: -+5% accuracy of the measurements would be OK.
Voltage between Phase Hi1 and common Zero.
Maybe you have any examples of these kind of switches or rectifiers? It would be very helpful..
I think we will find proper filters for that. Thank you for your help!